# UIView in the navigationItem shifted after change orientation iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, screen-orientation, uinavigationitem

there are two UIViews in the navigationItem (Detail Controller) in my iPad App.
After changing orientation to the portrait mode and back to the landscape mode, both UIViews are shifted by some pixels to the right.

```
lbNavTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
rbNavTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

unfortunately this code doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following:

```
CGRect headerDoubleTitleFrame;
self.navigationItem.titleView.frame = headerDoubleTitleFrame;
```

that should avoid shifting of the UIViews in the navigationItem